# Printing out the matrix with overloaded << operator

Tags: c++

I have 2d array, that represents matrix and I need to print it via overloaded << operator.

The declaration of that overloaded operator is

```
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Matrix &matrix) {

return os;
}
```

and it works well - when I write

```
 ostringstream os;
 Matrix a;
 // fill in the matrix
 os << a;
```

this function is called...but although I've read some tutorials, I didn't find out, how to make it to print out the values... Can somebody pls show me on soma sample code, how to implement some very basic operation of printing out the values from matrix?

btw-the matrixes can have random sizes..

Comment: It depends on the class `Matrix`, which you haven't shown...

Comment: pls look at the comment bellow  @Paul R's answer

Answer (score 1):

You either need to write the result from the `ostringstream` to `cout`:

```
ostringstream os;
Matrix a;
// fill in the matrix
os << a;
cout << os.str();
```

or you do it directly:

```
Matrix a;
// fill in the matrix
cout << a;
```

Comment: as I've commented bellow - I can't...I've found some solution with usage of sprintf, that could work, but I wasn't able to make it work..  `char buf[40];
 snprintf (buf, sizeof buf,
  "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
  y, m, d, h, min, s);

 os << buf;`

Comment: @Dworza Sorry to be blunt, but your question and comments make no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `Matrix` class definition it's hard to guess how it's implemented, but you probably want something like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, const Matrix &matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.cols; ++j)
            os << " " << matrix.data[i * matrix.cols + j];
        os << std::endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

To display the matrix you would then just do this:

```
 Matrix a;
 // fill in the matrix
 cout << a;
```

This invokes the above `operator<<` implementation to print the matrix to stdout. Obviously you can use any other appropriate output stream instead of `cout`.

Comment: nope...I know, how to get values from matrix and how to iterate through forloops...IE this code: `std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Matrix &matrix) {
    cout<<"printing"<<endl;
    os << "qwerty";
    return os;
}` it prints out "printing" to the console, nevertheless "qwerty" isn't printed at all :-/

Comment: OK - I think you just need to use `cout` rather than create an `ostringstream` - see edit above.

Comment: I would like to use `cout`, but I can't... I really must use the template I've posted here...

Comment: What template ? The above `operator<<` will work with any `ostringstream`, but if you want to display the matrix on stdout then you just need to use `cout` as shown above.

Comment: the overloaded operator, that shall return `ostream` and printing will be initialized with `os << a;`

Comment: I think you're really just misunderstanding how stream operators work.

Comment: @Dworza So what *are* you allowed to use to print output to stdout if not `cout`? Can you use `printf`? What about `printf("%s", os.str())`?